# Is JSON-LD compaction supposed to remove the at @ from @id and @type?

Tags: json-ld

If you visit the JSON-LD playground page here, and click the "Person" example (which, as of this writing, is [this](http://json-ld.org/playground/?startTab=tab-expanded&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2F%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22Person%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Jane%20Doe%22%2C%22jobTitle%22%3A%22Professor%22%2C%22telephone%22%3A%22(425)%20123-4567%22%2C%22url%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.janedoe.com%22%7D)), then the output of the compaction contains an attribute called "type", not "@type" which is what I would expect (since the latter corresponds to the JSON-LD type keyword).

What is it about the compaction algorithm that removes the at symbol from the type?  If you click on the "Activity" example, the compacted result does contain "@type".  Why is there a difference in processing these two inputs?

Comment: This results in labels starting with `@` for me. Suggest you ask the owners of the web site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature called [Keyword Aliasing](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#aliasing-keywords). Schema.org recently added a keyword alias form `@type` to just `type` and `@id` to `id` to their context and that's why you set that. The compact tab of the person example uses Schema.org's context for the compaction.